Why do these two methods of implementing Positional Encoding in the Transformer model output different results？
The first heatmap is the result of method _positional_encoding, and the second one is the result of method _positional_encoding_vector:


I think they are all implement of Positional Encoding in standard Transformer, why the result is different? Please give me a hand, thank you so much!
class PositionalEncoding:
    def __init__(self, embed_size: int, vector: bool = True):
        self.embed_size = embed_size
        self.vector = vector

    def __call__(self, input_x: torch.tensor) -> torch.Any:
        return self._positional_encoding_vector(input_x, self.embed_size) if self.vector else self._positional_encoding(input_x, self.embed_size)

    def _positional_encoding_vector(self, input_x: torch.tensor, embed_size: int):
        batch_size, seq_len = input_x.shape[0], input_x.shape[1]
        pos_encoding = torch.zeros(batch_size, seq_len, embed_size)
        pos_encoding_element = torch.arange(0, seq_len)[..., None].tile(
            (1, embed_size)
        ) / (
            10000
            ** ((torch.arange(embed_size) // 2) / embed_size)[None, ...].tile(seq_len, 1)
        )
        pos_encoding[..., 0::2] = torch.sin(pos_encoding_element[..., 0::2])
        pos_encoding[..., 1::2] = torch.cos(pos_encoding_element[..., 1::2])

        return pos_encoding

    def _positional_encoding(self, input_x: torch.tensor, embed_size: int):
        batch_size, seq_len = input_x.shape[0], input_x.shape[1]
        pos_encoding = torch.zeros(batch_size, seq_len, embed_size)
        for i in range(embed_size):
            if i % 2 == 0:
                pos_encoding[:, :, i] = torch.sin(
                    torch.arange(0, seq_len) / 10000 ** (i / embed_size)
                )
            else:
                pos_encoding[:, :, i] = torch.cos(
                    torch.arange(0, seq_len) / 10000 ** ((i - 1) / embed_size)
                )
        return pos_encoding

